# How do I get 'id' from database to update a particular row?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a row which is already in database, and  i am using above code for that but it gives me error as 'undefined id', so how can i do this.....please help me!!!

```
if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $getid="select id from login";
    $res=mysql_query($getid);
    $ids=$_GET[$row['id']];

    $about=$_POST['desc'];
    $pri=$_POST['price'];
    $ride=$_POST['fly'];
    $city=$_POST['ct'];

    $flt="";
    foreach($ride as $entry) {
        $flt .= $entry.",";
    }
    $ct="";
    foreach($city as $entry) {
        $ct .= $entry.",";
    }

    $query ="UPDATE login SET rides='$flt',price=$pri,about='$about',city='$ct' WHERE id='$ids'";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    echo $result;
    if(!$result) {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("something went Wrong...:("); 
        location.href="edit.php"';
        echo '</script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("successfully updated!!!"); 
        location.href="edit.php"';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the total error message?mysql_* queries have been deprecated in php5 and removed in php7.

Comment: you have missed the $ in id=$ids and what does the $ids contains??

Comment: The entire $ids variable is set wrong. You've not even completed returning the query results.

Comment: i have to get id from my database.....it error as 'undefined variable:row' and 'undefined index:id'

Comment: $_GET[$row['id']] what does it do ?? because this you have getting error

Comment: by giving quoted value as "id=1" it works fine but i dont want it....i want to get it from DB!!!

Comment: Check out https://www.w3schools.com/ php-mysqli section first.  Your code is entirely faulty.

Comment: Voting close for this reason "*sorry guys i am new to php so please give me entire answer!!! – Rkboss 2 mins ago*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$res=mysql_query($getid); $ids=$_GET[$row['id']];
```

You need to fetch the id by executing and fetching 
If you want all `ids` then you must store it in array and then implode it or concatenate in a single variable then use it in `where` condition of update query use IN clause

Answer (score 0):

fetch the id from the database use the $conn variable to execute the query use mysqli instead of mysql

```
$getid="select id from login";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$getid);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
$ids[]=$row['id'];
}
```

Comment: If 100 records present. Then, it will fetch only last record id. Not feasible way.

Comment: have to store the id in the array

Comment: It is very easy to say *it doesnt work!!!:(*. But, you are having wrong logic. You are not clear with your question and logic @Rkboss